# How to automate addition of intents from existing intents list to existing AWS LEX BOT using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, android-intent, automation, amazon-lex

created a json file with intents and upload the same to S3.

From S3    using python created(put_intent api) the intents in AWS lex.

Intents    was added to existing intents list.

How can i add the newly created    intents to an existing BOT using python or how can i automate the    intent addition to existing Lex Bot from existing intents

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution and the solution is to use put_bot api in boto3 library. We should mention the intent list in put_bot api. put_bot will update or create a bot with the intents mentioned. If we are doing updation of a bot which has intents using put_bot api, then it removes all existing intents and only the intents mentioned in api call, which means it replace existing bot with new bot.